# File will be changed after copying to system32

Tags: c++, windows

I have a helper DLL that I'm using for a long time without any change in its signature and I copy it to `system32` in order to use it in all my products, now I add a function to its export list and compile it, everything looks OK and I have a new DLL that contain specified function. My problem is when I copy it into `system32` specified function is missing, it looks like somehow it will be copied from a cache and some old version of it will be loaded, so programs that depend on new function will be failed! does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Wild guess - there a bitness mismatch somewhere, and you've now got two different versions of the DLL in `C:\Windows\System32` and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you have a 64 bit system. You copy the file to the 64 bit system directory, system32. But, because of the file system redirector, your 32 bit application loads it from the 32 bit system directory, SysWOW64.

Solve the problem by copying to SysWOW64.

You probably know this, but I feel compelled to say it anyway. The system directory belongs to the system and you should not be writing to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to command to clear the dll cache. This has been tested on Win XP and Win 7.

```
sfc /purgecache
```

Please note that you need to be an admin to run this command or "Run as administrator". Not a 100% sure if this will fix your problem.

Comment: Won't this cache only affect system DLLs

Comment: Now that you asked I am confused :(

Comment: SFC="System Files check" - this file is not a Windows system file.

Comment: Agreed. I remember doing this a number of times when my dlls were not reflected and magically it used to work. Now I realize it must be something else that was fixing it. Enlightened :)